# htaccess rewrite condition not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on URL of my website. I have just rewrite the URL From

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?url=some-text
```

to

```
http://www.website.com/some-text
```

For this I'm using following code of .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, I want to add another variable `page number` in URL.

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?url=some-text&page=1
```

I want to rewrite it like

```
http://www.website.com/some-text/1/
AND
http://www.website.com/some-text/1
```

I have tried following code but some reason it is not working, it showing me server error.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, you rewrite the other way round. From `http://www.website.com/some-text` to `http://www.website.com/index.php?url=some-text`. You always start to look from the original request as the user enters the address. Just noting.

Comment: Did the first code work and only after you added the second line you get the internal server error? Also, if you get an internal server error, please check the error log of that server and tell use the reason. It most often contains a better description of the problem you'd like to know and add to your question.

Comment: why off topic?? please add comment so I can understand my mistake.

Comment: a) You ask about server configuration, not a programming question (this is a grey area so just noting) b) you don't ask a question. You dump server configuration, say there is an error but do not even provide the exact error message from your server logs. Just writing "not working" does not qualify as a programming question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: This is not server configuration question, I'm not posting any server configuration questions here, I know there is another website available for the sever configuration solution, this is htaccess issue. and htaccess issue is not server configuration issue but its a programming issue

Comment: It might be news to you, but the `.htaccess` files are part of the Apache server configuration. You should better read the product documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html - just read out loud the first sentence of that manual page.

Comment: so how can you say that its off topic? why this is not appearing on stackoverflow? there are lots of htaccess questions on stackoverflow.. now make them all off topic

Comment: It's kinda cheap to argue with so many wrong questions. They don't make yours right. Instead you should consider a bit about what I wrote. It's not all black or white, but there's soemthing for you to keep apart from just the codez.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't time to debate on it. but this is wrong, you can't make it off topic.

Comment: IMO question related to mod_rewrite relate to programming as much they relate to server config. More often than not folks are dealing with pretty URL schemes, SEO etc for their web applications and face some difficulties while dealing some regex issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 new rules. Just one with optional `/` will be enough. Your complete code:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Another problem in your new code is that `RewriteCond` are not getting applied for last `RewriteRule` since these are applicable to very next `RewriteRule` only.

Comment: its working but now css and javascript files are not applied.

Comment: That is most common problem people run into after switching to pretty URL. Solution is simple: make sure your js, css etc are always using absolute paths i.e. starting with `http://` or `/`

Comment: @Downvoter: For my education purpose please comment, why it got down voted?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I had provided proper reasoning also why earlier code didn't work. I guess some folks here who cannot answer themselves shows their frustration by downvoting a working and accepted solution like this.

Comment: well to be fair, this answer does not cover the "not working" part of the question. It was written that it is not working and there is an internal server error. This answer does not explain why there was an internal server error. Instead it moves that error just away so not answering but making the question obsolete. I don't think that such an answer is of much use if OP would have wanted to understand why there was the error in the first place. Imagine those who search for it find it and have the same error but different .htaccess configuration. Just saying.

Comment: @hakre my problem is now solved, and my explanation is also good that's why I got quick and proper answer. why you think the question is not proper?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: What kind of programming question? You have a server configuration issue and you want to learn more about server configuration. More especially you want to learn more about regular expressions. But you don't ask for that, instead all you state is here code, not working. That's pretty rough. You might find users who just give you the code because it's low hanging fruits for them, but you won't understand the problem much you're dealing with and would be only trained to ask the next question again. See the 100.000s .htaccess questions all similar and quite not one answer explains?

Comment: @hakre: Answer very much covers the reason for "not working" you didn't give enough attention to this part: **`RewriteCond are not getting applied for last RewriteRule since these are applicable to very next RewriteRule only`**